# Parse Recyclerview Data between fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in a fragment which displays a list of movies. i want to when user clicks item, it opens a new fragment which will be detailed page of that item.

I have tried bundles and intent putExtra but does not work, keeps coming up with null pointer error.

i have tried with Hardcoded strings as a test and works fine but trying to get item POJO data does not.

Anyone have an idea how to parse data between fragments from recyclerview onclick function?

1st Fragment which displays recyclerview data:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment  {

    private static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private MovieAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    private TextView title;

    private final static String API_KEY = "670d03a721dd007862c0181bfd097e5d";

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initData();
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movies_recycler_view);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {


                FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                MovieDetail movieDetail = new MovieDetail();
                //Bundle Send Data
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("title", movieList.get(position).getTitle());
                movieDetail.setArguments(bundle);
                fragTrans.replace(R.id.container_body, movieDetail);
                fragTrans.isAddToBackStackAllowed();
                fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
                fragTrans.commit();



            }
        }));



        return rootView;

    }

    private void initData() {

        ApiInterface api = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<MovieResponse> call = api.getMostPopularMovies(API_KEY);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {

                int statusCode = response.code();
                List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MovieAdapter(movies, R.layout.list_item_movie, getContext()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d(TAG, t.toString());

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

}
```

Detail Fragment:

```
public class MovieDetail extends Fragment {
    private TextView titleTv;
    public MovieDetail() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_detail, container, false);
        titleTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailTitleTV);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        titleTv.setText(String.valueOf(bundle.getString("title")));
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
    /**
     * .
     */
}
```

i have looked at other questions similar but they deal with hardcoded Strings not POJO data for item click. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class which extends parcelable and then pass the object in the bundle, then access each field with get methods.

Comment: have you got an example of this i can see